# What is wrong with the WHERE clause in this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

```
select *
from tblProduct full join tblProductSales on tblProduct.id = tblProductSales.id
where tblProduct.id <> tblProductSales.id;
```

I fixed the syntax errors and it still won't run. I keep getting the following error:

> unknown column 'tblProduct.id' in 'where clause'

Note that there is a column 'id' in the table 'tblProduct'

Comment: Odd. But your query makes no sense anyway.

Comment: show us the structure of tblProduct table

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddafd271a91b6b781fd5d4b6dfe6e9b3

Comment: What syntax errors did you fix? MySql does not even support full join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql does not support full joins, the error does not describe the problem.

One workaround for full joins in MySql would be to union two queries to return all from left, with gaps, and all from the right, with gaps.

> ```
> create table tblProduct (id integer);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table tblProductSales (id integer);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tblProduct VALUES (1),(2),(3),(8),(9),(9);
>
> INSERT INTO tblProductSales VALUES (1),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
>
>
> SELECT * FROM tblProduct P
> LEFT JOIN tblProductSales S ON P.id = S.id
> UNION ALL
> SELECT * FROM tblProduct P
> RIGHT JOIN tblProductSales S ON P.id = S.id
> WHERE P.id IS NULL
> ```

> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
>   id |   id
> ---: | ---:
>    1 |    1
>    1 |    1
>    2 |    2
>    3 |    3
>    8 | null
>    9 | null
>    9 | null
> null |    4
> null |    5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba70831968044893f5f54bcba643cb5d)*

Comment: What happens if you instead do `INSERT INTO tblProductSales VALUES (1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(4),(5);`

Comment: BTW, p left join s is the same as s right join p.

Comment: @jarlh - I reversed the tables and am still thinking about your first comment.

Comment: You have to do UNION ALL.

Comment: And make sure the RIGHT JOIN doesn't return any common rows (I.e. P rows.)

Comment: @jarlh - I worked with it a bit and think I have it.

Comment: Yes, now it's a FULL OUTER JOIN!

Answer (score -3):

When you use uppercase letters in SQL use quotation marks both for table names and columns. Try:

```
select * from "tblProduct" 
full join "tblProductSales" on "tblProduct".id = "tblProductSales".id
where "tblProduct".id <> "tblProductSales".id;
```

Comment: Is your recommendation documented anywhere?